# Google sign in for iOS using firebase is giving 400 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Sign in for iOS, I followed all the steps mentioned on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin to setup Google sign in, but when I get the `GIDSignInDelegate` callback

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
```

I get HTTP error code as 400 with user object as `nil` and description as

```
Error data:
{
    error = "invalid_grant";
    "error_description" = "verifier does not match.";
}
```

My code is pretty simple, just implemented a Google sign in button and my View controller implements GIDSignInDelegate.

Demo code:

```
In AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.clientID;

    PBLoginSignupUserViewController *loginSignupVC = [[PBLoginSignupUserViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginSignupVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}

In MyViewController.m <GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate>

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    // GETTING ERROR HERE, AND nil AS USER OBJECT

    if(!error){
        GIDAuthentication *authentication = user.authentication;
        FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRGoogleAuthProvider credentialWithIDToken:authentication.idToken
                                                                         accessToken:authentication.accessToken];
    } else {
        // show toast for error
    }
}
```

Comment: have you enabled google sign-in service and added/updated the configuration file some [google-service-info.plist] in your project??

Comment: @nikdange_me Yes, I have configured all that.

Comment: I had the same problem once, it was a configuration issue. You should try to reconfig setup again, we 'may' miss step sometimes.

Comment: @nikdange_me I have tried that with a new single view application, the steps are pretty simple and I guess there is nothing much to miss. If you get any clue then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to search for 'invalid_grant' error, it related to OAuth2 service. I am just trying to help you, this may not be the solution.

Comment: read this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift and check if any of your code is missing.

Comment: @JenJose I followed this too, it is exactly same as given on the Firebase website, I have reconfigured 2-3 times. Don't know where my code is going wrong, or I am missing something on the server side.

Comment: i am pretty much sure that you aren't missing anything in Firebase console and I am equally confident that the issue is in google GIdSignin. Can you share demo ?

Comment: Found a helpful article related to this: https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35#.n62pyj4fj

Comment: @JenJose I have updated my question with the demo code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: any luck with this code ?